# How to convert randomly generated array to pandas series

Tags: arrays, pandas, list

Created array by randomly selected list

```
import random

import numpy as np

fruits = ['orange','mango','apple']

np.random.choice(fruits, 7, replace=True)
```

Output

```
array(['orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'mango', 'apple'],
      dtype='<U6')
```

Generated series from above array

```
fruits = pd.Series(fruits)

fruits
```

Output

```
0    orange

1     mango

2     apple

dtype: object
```

Output requirement: Array elements have 7. After converting to Series, generated only 3 items. But I wanted to generate pandas series by 7 items.

```
0 orange

1 mango

2 apple

3 orange

4 orange

5 mango

6 apple

dtype: object
```

Comment: You are not assigning random array to fruit variable ie. output of first cell to variable, that might be the issue

Answer (score 1):

```
fruit_series = pd.Series(np.random.choice(fruits, 7, replace=True))
fruit_series
```

returns:

```
0    orange
1     mango
2    orange
3     apple
4     apple
5     apple
6     apple
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign random fruits list in a variable

```
import numpy as np
fruits = ['orange','mango','apple']
random_fruits = np.random.choice(fruits, 7, replace=True)
s = pd.Series(random_fruits)
print(s)
```

[image]